# Can't upgrade to 17.04 due to full /boot, already cleaned old kernels

Tags: boot, partitioning, upgrade, disk-usage

I've a `/boot` partition with `232MiB` inside. Of those, `102.2MiB` are free.

I've already performed any possible necessary cleanup, have only 2 (two) kernels installed, with each taking around `50MiB`:

```
$ sudo du * -h | sort -n
1.0K    lost+found
1.4M    abi-4.8.0-42-generic
1.4M    abi-4.8.0-46-generic
2.1M    grub.bak/i386-pc
2.1M    grub/i386-pc
2.3M    grub/fonts
2.4M    grub.bak/fonts
3.9M    System.map-4.8.0-42-generic
3.9M    System.map-4.8.0-46-generic
4.4M    grub.bak
6.8M    grub
7.2M    vmlinuz-4.8.0-42-generic
7.2M    vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
41M     initrd.img-4.8.0-42-generic
41M     initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
126K    grub/locale
180K    memtest86+.bin
182K    memtest86+.elf
182K    memtest86+_multiboot.bin
196K    config-4.8.0-42-generic
196K    config-4.8.0-46-generic
726K    extlinux/themes/debian-wheezy
727K    extlinux/themes
781K    extlinux
```

I've now tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.04 via `update-manager -d`, and it fails complaining about lack of space on `/boot`. This seems unreasonable to me.

I could very well resize `/boot`, but since it is already over what nearly all sources recommend, I'm afraid this is going to turn into a regular thing (and it takes quite some time for me since `/boot` is currently squeezed between other partitions).

Should I just remove the `/boot` partition and merge it with `/`? What am I risking in doing so?

Comment: 232mb is quite low. I used to have mine set for that and was forever running out of space. I increased it to 500mb, it's not like I'll miss the space from elsewhere. Yes, some guides will tell you 250mb minimum, but that's MINIMUM. You've got that, and your system works, so technically it's accurate. But you need to constantly maintain /boot when it has so little space. Bump it up to 500mb or even 1gb and you'll never need to worry about running out of space. If it's in between partitions, steal the space from the one to the left if you can - it'll be quicker

Comment: @Will I'll shift everything over then. LVM partitions are a pain to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

If you have performed a system update, reboot your machine and execute the following command:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

This will remove all the old kernels and generate a new Grub menu for you which will contain only the current kernel that you are using. You can then try an upgrade and see if the error has gone. Source:

https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/

Comment: I know I can remove the last remaining kernel, but I'd prefer not to, since as a solution it would be way too brittle. Also keeping at least a backup kernel seems reasonable in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Then maybe you should resize the boot partition using  GParted. First, decrease the size of a partition according to your settings, lets say /home and then increase your boot partition to the desired size. A livecd is recommended to make such changes.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this is a known bug that's been fixed; but the fix won't help you, since the size is set when you install Ubuntu. See the bug report here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1465050

You might be able to do the update by removing the kernel you're not currently using. (I'd use `dpkg` for this, so that the changes are tracked in the package manager.) This may free up just enough space for the upgrade. Be aware that you're likely to bump into the partition's size limits soon thereafter, though, so resizing `/boot` (or creating a new and larger `/boot`) is desirable in the long run.